# Call to a member function connection() on null after clearing the cache

Tags: laravel, caching

After running this command `php artisan config:clear` in laravel 5.6, I'm facing this issue:[image]

Now neither the config:clear is working nor the project is running.

Comment: In which file I need to add it "parent::setUp()"?

Comment: Execute `php artisan config:clear -vvv`, you'll have the full trace and you may be able to tell what is happening.

Comment: **Uncomment**  `$app->withFacades();` AND  `$app->withEloquent();` lines in `bootstrap/app.php;`

Comment: @toyi On running this command getting this error  "Call to a member function connection() on null"

Comment: @VikasKatariya There is no line like this If I do add then getting this error: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::withFacades() in /var/www/html/hobycleanrs/bootstrap/app.php:29"